# Linking assemblies failed with BugSense for Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, bugsense, xamarin-linker

I'm trying to integrate BugSense into my Xamarin Android project.

I followed this [guide](https://www.bugsense.com/docs/xamarin) and when I built my project I got LinkAssemblies error:

`Error  1   error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.       0   0    Error   2   error MSB4018: Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'Android.Views.SurfaceOrientation Android.Views.Display::get_Rotation()' (defined in 'BugSense.Xamarin.Android, Version=3.6.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') from 'BugSense.Xamarin.Android, Version=3.6.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved.      0   0`

I tried to add BugSense library via Package Manager Console, then by adding DLL to References and then via NuGet. I built it with Visual Studio 2012 and also with Xamarin Studio but everything failed the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error suggests a problem with linking assemblies.

Try setting Linking to **None** in Project properties -> Android Options -> Configuration properties.

Answer (score 1):

`Xamarin.Android` applications use a **linker** in order to reduce the size of the application.The default value is `SdkOnly`

- `None`: No linking will be attempted.
- `SdkOnly`: Linking will be
  performed on the base class libraries only, not user's assemblies.
- `Full`: Linking will be performed on base class libraries and user
  assemblies.
  [For more details refer here..](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/)
  Note: if you are facing an issue with linking such as

> LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. or
>
> "GetAdditionalResourcesFromAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: . Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

then recheck your xamarin.Android project settings and set the below tag,

```
<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>true</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

add Api 21 and set its targeted Framework  5.0 and restart your Xamarin ..

its works on my system..

Answer (score -2):

In Release Mode for all Projects set
project prop => advances => Debug Info = Node